# How do I set a JavaScript variable to the contents of a textarea tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to set my JavaScript variable to whatever is typed into my first `<textarea>` tag but it is not working and I have no idea how to fix it as I do not have much experience with JavaScript. Any help from anyone is greatly appreciated. I haven't tried anything else since I couldn't think of anything to try.

```js
var t =  document.getElementById("text").value
function func() {
    document.getElementById("ascii").value = t;
}
```

```css
.con {
    display: flex; 
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.button {
    background: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 140px;
    border-radius: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.txt {
    display: flex; 
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.text {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 630px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    resize: none;
}

.asci {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.ascii {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 640px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>alphabetical order machine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ascii.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="con">
        <!--button onclick="func()">button</button-->
    <form class="txt">
        <textarea class="text" id="text" type="text" placeholder="type your text here!"></textarea>        
        <input class="button" type='button' value="alphabetize" onclick="func()">
    </form>
    <form class="asci">
        <textarea class="ascii" id="ascii" type="text"></textarea>
    </form>
    </div>
    <script src="ascii.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the the both lines in `func`. Currently you're reading the value of the first textarea before you're writing anything to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var t =  document.getElementById("text").value
function func() {
    document.getElementById("ascii").value = t;
}
```

Currently your `var t =  document.getElementById("text").value` code will only execute once. And the first time, the value will be "" since the textArea is empty the first time.

You need to move it inside the `func()` so that each time `func()` is executed, it will get the latest value

```
function func() {
    var t =  document.getElementById("text").value
    document.getElementById("ascii").value = t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your var declaration inside your function:

```
function func() {
   var t =  document.getElementById("text").value
   document.getElementById("ascii").value = t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the value of `t` only once without a way to find and get the value when the button is clicked. Any task that you want to do more than once must be in a function or a reoccurring expression, etc. The following demo declares only one variable outside the function and the rest is within the function -- details are commented in demo.

BTW if you are dealing with form fields (ex. input, output, textarea, etc), it would behoove you  to warp everything within a form and use the form to manage all form fields.

### Demo

```js
// Reference the form
const editor = document.forms.editor;

// Register the form to the input event
editor.oninput = edit;

// pass the event object
function edit(event) {

  /*
  = 'this' is the form
  = `field` is a NodeList of inputs, buttons, textareas, 
     etc
  */
  const field = this.elements;
  
  /*
  = event.target is the tag the user interacted with 
    In this case it would be textarea#in
  */
  const input = event.target;
  
  // Reference textarea#out
  const output = field.out;
  
  /*
  = if the event.target is textarea#in...
  = Set the value of textarea#out to the value of
    textarea#in 
  */
  if (input.id === 'in') {
    output.value = input.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id='editor'>
  <textarea id='in'></textarea>
  <textarea id='out'></textarea>
</form>
```